# Passing value of a variable to angularjs directive template function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to pass a $scope's variable to a directive, but its not working. I am catching the variable in the template function:

```
app.directive('customdir', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',

        template: function(element, attrs) {
            console.log(attrs.filterby);
            switch (attrs.filterby) {
                case 'World':
                    return '<input type="checkbox">';
            }
            return '<input type="text" />';
        }
    };
});
```

What I need is the value of variable `filterby` not the variable name itself.

[Plunkr Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/OQqLeUIoFNhkqSoeIdyM?p=preview)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Or like this

```
app.directive('customdir', function ($compile) {
  var getTemplate = function(filter) {
    switch (filter) {
      case 'World': return '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="filterby">';
      default:  return '<input type="text" ng-model="filterby" />';
    }
  }

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          filterby: "="
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var el = $compile(getTemplate(scope.filterby))(scope);
            element.replaceWith(el);
        }
    };
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/yPopi0mYdViElCKrQAq9?p=preview

Comment: Amazing thanks! Just what I needed. Some crazy ass logic there though! :)

Comment: @Vikas Singhal: I don't think that it's a good idea to choose a template based on `scope's attribute`. It should be a normal attribute for the directive. `scope's attributes` (model) should only be used by template (view) though binding

Comment: I understand that point, but I have a situation where I need to show a checkbox, inputbox, textarea or select based on a filter value. Feel free to suggest an alternative here.

Comment: @KhanhTO suppose form is dynamically created using JSON... that JSON would become scope model and would pass data to directive via attributes. Therefore I don't understand your concerns

Comment: @charlietfl: for example: the directive is a view to display a list of items with 2 modes (list view and tree view). We should configure the view by a property in the html directly by specifying this directive should display a list or a tree, the model should not contain a property to indicate the view for it. That's what I mean in my answer

Comment: Shouldn't filterby: "=" be filterby: = "@"

Comment: @KhanhTO How do I do something like this using the above method

    template: '<input type="hidden" {{disabled}}>'

where disabled is a variable passed to the directive.

Comment: @Shan: well, I'm not after this solution. If you try my solution (the second one in my answer), you don't even need $compile, just `<input type="hidden" ng-disabled="disabled">`

Comment: I like this solution, but be careful with your switch statement, it is missing ``break``'s

Answer (score 9):

Template should not contain logic because template is ***view***. Template should only contain binding directives to make the ***view*** updated based on changes of the scope (***model***). Something like this:

```
app.directive('customdir', function ($compile) {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',

        scope:{
          filterby:"="
        },

        link:function (scope, element) {
          scope.$watch("filterby",function(newValue){ //logic is out of template
              if (newValue == "World"){
                scope.showCheckBox = true;
              }
              else {
                scope.showCheckBox = false;
              }
          });
        },

        template: function(element, attrs) {
         //View should be passive and only listens to changes of model to update it accordingly.
            return '<input type="checkbox" ng-show="showCheckBox" / ><input type="text" ng-show="!showCheckBox"  />'; 
        }
    };
});
```

With this approach, you could even change the input at runtime and the view is updated to reflect the changes.

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/EjjFVB6kHaso975yEXUk?p=preview)

If you want to make a decision on which template to use based on some configuration, you should configure it via a normal property, should not access though scope's propery. Simply like this:

```
app.directive('customdir', function ($compile) {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            filterby:"=" //filterby is a separate field used for data binding
        },

        template: function(element, attrs) {
            switch (attrs.type) { //view selection configuration should be obtained from the element
                case 'checkbox':
                    return '<input type="checkbox">';
            }
            return '<input type="text" />';
        }
    };
});
```

Configure it by passing a normal value:

```
<customdir type="checkbox" filterby="name"></customdir>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/9ihLOlTr9o8nQWkFwvxM?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what is a `template` function? It should be a `link` function. Second, you're overloading  the link function incorrectly, order matters here, its always `scope, element, attrs` .Third, pass the variable in an isolate scope:

```
app.directive('customdir', function ($compile) {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:{
          filterby:'='
        },

        link: function(scope,element, attrs) {
            console.log(scope.filterby);
            switch (scope.filterby) {
                case 'World':
                    return '<input type="checkbox">';
            }
            return '<input type="text" />';
        }
    };
});
```

or if you insist on attributes then:

```
 app.directive('customdir', function ($compile) {

        return {
            restrict: 'E',

            link: function(scope,element, attrs) {
                console.log(attrs.filterby);
                switch (attrs.filterby) {
                    case 'World':
                        return '<input type="checkbox">';
                }
                return '<input type="text" />';
            }
        };
    });
```

but in your html:

```
 <customdir filterby="{{name}}"></customdir>
```

To ensure the variables value gets evaluated first. Finally you should not be manipulating the DOM like that, in fact that link function won't render html as you'd expect. You have a static template and your link function will act as something to set variable values on the template.

Comment: Again, does not work : http://plnkr.co/edit/pqmb5XWyCeXF44C85KZX?p=preview. Can you help me with the code itself and tell what exactly is right way?