# Passing variable to directive template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

What I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
<rule-type-selector class="protractor-test-rule-description" all-rule-types="allRuleTypes" local-value="$parent.$parent.currentRuleDescription" on-selection-change="onSelectNewRuleType()" disabled="disabled">
</rule-type-selector>
```

And in the directive

```
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      allRuleTypes: '&',
      localValue: '=',
      onSelectionChange: '&',
      disabled: '=' 
    },
    template: function($scope) {
      if($scope.disabled) {
        return '<input type="hidden" disabled>';
      }
      return '<input type="hidden">';
    }
```

This doesn't work. I always hit the 2nd return statement irrespective of whether disabled is set or not. 
I've looked at [Passing value of a variable to angularjs directive template function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20810862/passing-value-of-a-variable-to-angularjs-directive-template-function) but my use case seems to be a bit different.

Comment: `template` used as a function gets two arguments `element` and `attributes` object. There is no scope yet at this moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `$compile` service inside the `link` function of your directive.

You need a function that creates the template (let's say: getTemplate), then in the link function you use:

```
    element.html(getTemplate(parameter1, parameter2, ...));
```

Then:

```
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
```

Here's the applied example:
http://jsfiddle.net/hwndew2o/4/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when `template` is used as a function, it receives two arguments: element and attributes objects. There is no scope yet at this moment.

You can however do something like this in your case:

```
template: function() {
    return '<input type="hidden" ng-if="disabled" disabled>' + 
           '<input type="hidden" ng-if="!disabled">';
}
```

So you use `ng-if` directives to conditionally render necessary field based on `scope.disabled` property.